# How to set subplots and figure size in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I have defined a figure in Python with 4 subplots. The figure size is set at: `figsize=(10,10)`

However, the final graph is not a square but a rectangle. How can I modify this figure size? Is it possible to set the size of each subplot?

Thanks!

This is the code:

```
fig, ((ax0, ax1), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots (nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10,10))
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') # 'fivethirtyeight, ggplot'

asset_stats['W_ini'].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = False,
                          fontsize = 10, rot=0, ax=ax0)

ax0.set_ylabel('Peso (%)',fontsize = 10)
ax0.set_xlabel('Activo',fontsize = 10)
ax0.set_title('Ponderacion inicial',fontsize = 12)

asset_stats['RC_ini'].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = False, 
                           fontsize = 10, rot=0, color = 'r', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Contribución al riesgo (%)',fontsize = 10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Activo',fontsize = 10)
ax1.set_title('Contrib riesgo inicial',fontsize = 12)

asset_stats['W_ERC'].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = False, figsize=(15,5), 
                          fontsize = 10, rot=0, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('Peso (%)',fontsize = 10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Activo',fontsize = 10)
ax2.set_title('Ponderacion ERC',fontsize = 12)

asset_stats['RC_ERC'].plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = False, figsize=(15,5), 
                           fontsize = 10, rot=0, color = 'r', ax=ax3)
ax3.set_ylabel('Contribución al riesgo (%)',fontsize = 10)
ax3.set_xlabel('Activo',fontsize = 10)
ax3.set_title('Equal Risk Contribution',fontsize = 12)

plt.show()
```

[image: Figure with 4 subplots]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to check it in my environment because I don't have the data, but I would try the following first.

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved... I had a different figuresize for the figure (10,10) and  a different figuresize in some subplots (15,5), therefore this last one ruled over the figure one.